# Создание фигуры в результате пересечения фигур snap.svg

Tags: javascript, snapsvg

Как получить фигуру из пересечение двух кругов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var s = Snap('#q');
var circle1 = s.circle(50, 50, 50).attr({fill: '#000', stroke: 'red'});
var circle2 = s.circle(80, 80, 50).attr({fill: '#000', stroke: 'red'});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="q">
```

Comment: До сих пор не нашел решение.

Comment: 123478901234511